# Comparing value to enum isn't obvious in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, enums

I have very straightforward code:

```
enum Color { BLUE, RED }

class Brush { 
    color: Color

    constructor(values) { 
        this.color = values.color
    }
}

let JSON_RESPONSE = `{"color": "BLUE"}`

let brush = new Brush(JSON.parse(JSON_RESPONSE))
```

Now I want to make a check:

```
console.log(brush.color === Color.BLUE)
```

And it returns `false`.

I tried a few combinations like

```
brush.color === Color[Color.BLUE]
```

But, of course, got a compiler error.

The question is how to make quite a *basic* comparison `enum === enum`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript `enum`s are actually "named numeric constants."

From [the TypeScript documentation on `enum`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

> Enums allow us to define a set of named numeric constants.
>
> The body of an enum consists of zero or more enum members. Enum members have numeric value (*sic*) associated with them . . .

You should be using [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) instead:

```
type Color = "BLUE" | "RED";
```

---

### Full Code ([View Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Color%20%3D%20%22BLUE%22%20%7C%20%22RED%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Brush%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20color%3A%20Color%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(values)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20values.color%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20JSON_RESPONSE%20%3D%20%60%7B%22color%22%3A%20%22BLUE%22%7D%60%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20brush%20%3D%20new%20Brush(JSON.parse(JSON_RESPONSE))%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(brush.color%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22BLUE%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%3D%3E%20true)):

```
type Color = "BLUE" | "RED";

class Brush { 
    color: Color

    constructor(values) { 
        this.color = values.color
    }
}

let JSON_RESPONSE = `{"color": "BLUE"}`

let brush = new Brush(JSON.parse(JSON_RESPONSE))

console.log(brush.color === "BLUE"); //=> true
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative ([*available since TS 2.4*](https://mariusschulz.com/blog/string-enums-in-typescript)) is [**String enums**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums):

```
enum Color {
  BLUE = "BLUE",
  RED = "RED"
}

console.log('BLUE' === Color.BLUE); // true
```

As there's no reverse mapping for string enums (at least in 2020), one might strongly consider inlining those with `const` modifier.