# Evaluate enum in Angular

Tags: typescript, if-statement, enums, compare

I have an enum implemented in the component `dog` like this:

```
export enum Sex {
  FEMALE,
  MALE
}
```

In another component I have that:

```
import {Dog, Sex} from "../../dto/dog";

[...]

@Input() dog: Dog;

[...]

isFemale(): boolean {
  let dogSex: Sex;
  dogSex = this.dog.sex;
  console.log(typeof dogSex);
  console.log(dogSex);
  if (dogSex === Sex.FEMALE) {
    console.log("F");
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log("M");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The console log reads

> string
> FEMALE
> M

Now that's weird. But what's even more weird is that Angular won't compile if I evaluate

```
if (dogSex === "FEMALE")
```

and states, I cannot compare type `Sex` to a string.

What's going on here and how can I solve this?

Comment: Did you mean to use a string `enum Sex {Female = "FEMALE"}`? Everything about your output seems reasonable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing value to enum isn't obvious in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43011707/comparing-value-to-enum-isnt-obvious-in-typescript)

Comment: @AluanHaddad actually I just wanted to use an "ordinary" enum. But I don't really know. I am new to TypeScript and this is quite confusing.

Comment: Then your would need to write `if (dogSex === Sex.FEMALE)` but, given what is printed to the console, the actual `dogSex` property holds a string and not a number. `enum` members are numbers by default

Comment: I thought so too. But how can it be a String, if the class demands it to be an enum of type `Sex`?

Comment: Type declarations do not exist and certainly therefore cannot be validated it runtime. Your property declaration is clearly wrong